# VBA how to exclude empty cell in condition?

Tags: excel, vba

`If sngRow.Cells(1,23) = "ready for pickup" then..`

what I would like is :

`If sngRow.Cells(1,23) = "ready for pickup" and sngRow.Cells(1,22) is NOT EMPTY then..`

I don't know how to write it in VBA and can't seem to find an easy solution

Comment: `If sngRow.Cells(1,23).value = "ready for pickup" and sngRow.Cells(1,22).value <> "" Then`

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to check this. I would recommend the `IsEmpty()` function

```
Sub test1()
    Debug.Print Not IsEmpty(sngRow.Cells(1, 22))
    Debug.Print VarType(sngRow.Cells(1, 22)) <> vbEmpty
    Debug.Print sngRow.Cells(1, 22) <> "" ' If there is an error in the cell (e.g. division by 0), a type mismatch error occurs
    Debug.Print sngRow.Cells(1, 22) <> vbNullString ' If there is an error in the cell (e.g. division by 0), a type mismatch error occurs
    Debug.Print TypeName(sngRow.Cells(1, 22).Value) <> "Empty"
End Sub
```

Comment: Just for fun: `Debug.Print InStr(sngRow.Cells(1, 22).Value(12),"<z:row/>") <> vbEmpty`, where `.Value(12)` stands for `.Value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML)` checking the [recordset representation of the specified range as XML formatted string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlrangevaluedatatype) :-)